# Auto load balancing two node Cluster Hyper-v 2008 R2 enterprise?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hyper-v, cluster

My setup is a 2 node cluster with 72GB ram each and a ~10TB MD3000i Iscsi SAN.  I have about 30VMs running I keep about 15 on either server. I do a live migration to the other server if I need to run updates or whatever...  Either one of the servers is able of running all VM if needed, but the cpu is pretty high.

Here's my issues. I know Hyper-v has a limit of a single Live-migration at a time. But Why doesn't it queue them up to move one at a time? If I multi select I don't get the option to live migrate a one at a time. OR if I'm in the process of Migrating one it will give me an error that it's currently migrating a VM... Is there a button I missed that will tell a Node that it needs to migrate all the VMs elsewhere?

Another question, does anyone know whats the best way to load balance VMs based on CPU and/or network utilzation. I have some VMs that don't do much. and some that trash the CPU or network. I'd like to balance it out on both servers if at all possible. and Is there any way to automate it?

last question... If I overcommit my Cluster is there a way to tell the cluster that I want certian VMs the be running and to savestate other VMs based on availible system resources? Say when my one node blue screens and the other node begins starting the VMs up. I want the unimportant ones to shutdown or savestate so the important ones can stay running or come back online.

Thanks just for reading all that. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesn't it queue them up to move
>   one at a time?

STUPID design decision. They have no problem queueing other operations (like shutdown).

> does anyone know whats the best way to
>   load balance VMs based on CPU and/or
>   network utilzation.

You know SCVMM (System Center Virtual Machine Manager)? Not sure it does enough for you, though.

> If I overcommit my Cluster is there a
>   way to tell the cluster that I want
>   certian VMs the be running and to
>   savestate other VMs based on availible
>   system resources?

No ;(